# How to aggregate pandas Dataframe by day

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I have got the following pandas DataFrame:

```
time,                value
2018-08-02 09:19:37, 2
2018-08-02 09:19:47, 3
2018-08-02 09:19:57, 6
......
2018-08-03 04:49:27, 2
2018-08-03 04:49:37, 4
2018-08-03 04:49:47, 5
```

I would like to build an output dataFrame as in the following:

```
time,                value
2018-08-02 11:59:59, AVG(2+3+6+..)
2018-08-03 11:59:59, AVG(2+4+5+..)
```

Please any help would very appreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.time.dt.date).value.mean()` ??

Comment: I tried but i get pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: change the dtype of value, `df.value=df.value.astype(int)` and then try, check my answer for detailed explaination

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Resample`

```
>>>df['time'] = df['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')    
>>>df.resample('D', on='time').mean()
>>>        
time         value
2018-08-02  3.666667
2018-08-03  3.666667
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use:

```
m=df.groupby(df.time.dt.date).value.mean().reset_index()
m.time=pd.to_datetime(m.time.astype(str)+' 11:59:59')
print(m)

                 time     value
0 2018-08-02 11:59:59  3.666667
1 2018-08-03 11:59:59  3.666667
```

**Note :** *If the dtypes are string , use the below first before the above code:*

```
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.value=df.value.astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Before I vote. Please can you confirm that fact that your sol average all the value from 00:00:00 to 11:59:59?

Comment: Sure. I will do it.  Please can you confirm that fact that your sol average all the value from 00:00:00 to 11:59:59?

Comment: @CarloAllocca this solution groups on the date and adds `11:59:59` as a string to each output. then converts to `datetime` so each row in `time` col will have `11:59:59`

Comment: so it does it automatically as it consider all the values within the same date. Thanks.

Comment: @CarloAllocca yes. :) group on just the date and append the max time of the day to the time col